# HTTPS on server running Tomcat and IIS

Tags: iis, https

I have a server running Tomcat along with IIS 7.5. I would like to know if it is possible to have https traffic going to Tomcat as well as https traffic on a sub-domain name going to IIS.

My assumption is that this is not possible, but would like some confirmation and maybe just a little clarification on the subject.

Added:
Looks like this might be possible with Url rewrite in IIS, but I cannot specify the port in the host name of the rule.

Answer (score 0):

If you have your site configured in IIS and running under http I don't see why not.

Create a self signed ssl certificate from root of your IIS > Server Certificates and add a new binding to your site using https and the certificate you just created.

For the subdomain, you can create another entry on IIS, using the same certificate (different port) or same port if you use a wildcard ssl certificate.